# Can I add bookmarks in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, bookmarks

Can I add bookmarks at certain code lines in Xcode 4? I'm currently using breakpoints for this purpose, but when I add/delete some code before the positions of the breakpoints, they don't shift accordingly, and therefore no longer point to the original lines. I have to manually adjust them. That's too bad.

Comment: Just curious: is there a specific workflow where you find bookmarks useful? Never made much sense to me.

Comment: Not a workflow. Just hard to find a certain method in a file of 4000 lines.

Comment: @benzado When I was studying a part of quite a big project (60K source files), I was adding "class A", "class B" bookmarks and then could simply locate class's definition by clicking. Searching is not an option, as it takes minutes, and breakpoints are not either, because you can not give them names.

Comment: I'm writing code, realize I need to add a `#import`, so I mark my current location, jump to the top, add the import, and then use my mark to jump back. Or I'm copying lines from various places in a file to one place. I mark them all and start jumping/copying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `#pragma mark My Fancy Bookmark` directly in your code and even `#pragma mark -` for a separation line. The bookmarks will appear under the title bar when you click on the name of the current function.

Comment: I know. That seems better for sections rather than bookmarks. You have to scroll down the function name list.